# How do I change my WhatsApp number without losing my chat history?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, google-backup, samsung-galaxy-tab-3

I am using Samsung Galaxy Tab 3. I have important messages on my WhatsApp. Though my phone is backed up by Google Drive every night, I do not know how to use it for changing my number without losing my history chat.

Is there any way that I can restore my chat history, especially chats with a personal contact, when I change my number?

Comment: Did you check the FAQ of WhatsApp thoroughly? It's available on its website. Show us [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far to answer your own question?

Answer (score 2):

Please check [the FAQ on the WhatsApp website](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/27585377). The process is fairly simple.

> **Before beginning the Change Number process**
>
> - Make sure your new phone number can receive SMS and/or calls and has an active data connection.
> - Make sure your old phone number is currently verified in WhatsApp on your phone. You can find the number currently verified on WhatsApp by going to the Payment Info screen (WhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Account > Payment info).
>
> > Note: When you change your WhatsApp phone number, your contacts will not individually be informed of the change. Only participants that share group chats with you will see that you changed your number. For a seamless messaging experience, notify your contacts that your number will be changing before you begin this process.
>
> **Changing your phone number**
>
> To change your phone number within WhatsApp, follow these steps:
>
> - Insert the new SIM card with the new number into your device.
> - Open WhatsApp.
> - Check if your old phone number is currently verified in WhatsApp by going to WhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Account > Payment info.
> - Go to WhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Account > Change number. Enter your old phone number in the top box.
> - Enter your new phone number in the bottom box.
> - Tap Done at the top of the screen.
> - You will be prompted to verify your new phone number.