# Changing number to new phone but keeping chat history

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When I tried to restore up my old chat backup from Google Drive to my new number on a new phone, WhatsApp didn't detect it. Does this mean I can only transfer chat history if it's the same number? If so how can I move my old chats to a new phone with a different number?

Comment: I don't think this can be possible. First you need to swap numbers. Log in with your old number then swap to the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Chat history backup and restore feature can be used only to change the mobile device. Because the backup will be taken for the particular mobile number and can be restored in the same number.

[How do I change my WhatsApp number without losing my chat history?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124677/how-do-i-change-my-whatsapp-number-without-losing-chat-history)

There is an inbuilt option in WhatsApp Messenger to change the phone number without losing the chat history. Please read the official documentation to do the same.

- https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/27585377
- https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28030001/?category=5245246